# how to set wpf MessageBox.Owner to desktop window because SplashScreen closes MessageBox

Tags: wpf, messagebox

I am using the **SplashScreen** feature in WPF by setting a bitmap's **Build Action** to Splashscreen. Behind the splash screen, licensing information is being check, and if it fails I show a **MessageBox**.

According to this [Feedback](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=381980&wa=wsignin1.0), it is because the MessageBox.Owner is the splash screen and as soon as another window is open even if it is a MessageBox the splash screen window is closed which then in turn closes the MessageBox, so the user never sees the MessageBox.

So the workaround would be to set the MessageBox.Owner to another window, but that would mean that I have to instantiate another window which might not even be needed.

Would it be possible to set the MessageBox.Owner to the desktop window? And how, because the only other function that comes to mind is the **GetDesktopWindow()** api function, but that returns a window handle and MessageBox.Owner is a WPF Window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. I am also using the build-in splash screen which causes this: [WPF SplashScreen closes MessageBox](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=381980&wa=wsignin1.0)

Comment: The question would now be how would you set the owner of the MessageBox to the deskop window?

Answer (score 11):

Since using the desktop window as the parent for your modal dialogs is not a good idea, as @Nir pointed out in his answer, here are three other workarounds:

1) Use a hidden window. Create a tiny, non-modal window to act as the parent for your MessageBox or other modal dialog. This approach is described here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/116bcd83-93bf-42f3-9bfe-da9e7de37546/

2) Create non-modal message windows. Change your startup mode to explicit shutdown and use a non-modal window to display your message. This approach is described in the answer to this StackOverflow question:

[MessageBox with exception details immediately disappears if use splash screen in WPF 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891719/messagebox-with-exception-details-immediately-disappears-if-use-splash-screen-in)

3) Call MessageBox twice. Apparently, the problem only affects the first modal dialog shown. So you could simply call your modal dialog twice, if you didn't mind the flash of the first one opening and closing.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/600197/wpf-splash-screen-dismisses-dialog-box

Personally, I don't like any of these workarounds. The only other option is to avoid the built-in SplashScreen functionality and to roll your own from scratch. Here's a link if you want to investigate that route further:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/8dd49fd0-9cc9-43c6-b285-6f119ab8a32e/

Finally, if you're as annoyed by this issue as I am, you can vote for Microsoft to fix this bug here:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/600197/wpf-splash-screen-dismisses-dialog-box

Answer (score 9):

I came up with this solution myself, so maybe there's something wrong with it, but it seems to work perfectly:

```
Window temp = new Window() { Visibility=Visibility.Hidden };
temp.Show();
MessageBox.Show(temp, "An error occurred before the application could start.\n\nTechnical Details: " + ex.Message, "Fatal Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Stop);
App.Current.Shutdown(1);
```

Comment: Nice and simple workaround. However, the `Visibility=Visibility.Hidden` isn't really needed, as you are going to show the window anyway. Instead, in order to avoid the splash display of the background window, I used: `new Window { WindowState = WindowState.Minimized, ShowInTaskbar = false }`

Comment: `new Window { AllowsTransparency = true,ShowInTaskbar=false,WindowStyle=WindowStyle.None, Background=Brushes.Transparent}` can make window completely hidden while setting the visibility or window state will cause window to be shown for a few millisec when `Show()` is invoke.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post some code? I just tried adding this to the App.xaml.cs file in a new WPF application:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Start app?", "Confirm Start", 
        MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.No)
    {
        this.Shutdown();
        return;
    }

    this.StartupUri = new Uri("Window1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

... and it works as expected (the "Confirm Start" prompt stays open until I've responded, and if I click "No" the app shuts down).

Comment: Matt, I also tested it like you did and realized it does work, because I was using a splash screen, it closes the MessageBox, without the splash screen it did not close

Comment: So I guess now you need to decide whether to close the question as "No longer relevant" or (as @adriaanp suggests in his comment) rework it as a different question.

Answer (score 0):

The desktop window is never the correct parent, read this to know why:

http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/24/79212.aspx

Now the problem described in this post doesn't happen so much because MS worked around it, in this post you can see how:

http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/11/02/931674.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This issue is still an issue, I faced it recently. For me, the solution was to close immediately the splash screen in case of any issues:

```
        SplashScreen splash = new(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(GuiApp))!, "Resources/img_my.png");
        splash.Show(false);

        using ServiceProvider? services = initializeApp();

        if (services == null)
        {
            splash.Close(TimeSpan.Zero);
            return -3;
        }
```

After that MessageBox displayed normally.

Answer (score -1):

this has helped me a lot .....
Given me new idea
but the example code that i have seen here has some modification required

here is an simple example in wpf with modification 
now it  is working

on button click

paste this code

if (System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("are u sure", "delete", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Question) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("why not to delete");
            }

Answer (score -1):

This is not directly related to the OP's situation, but might be useful for others who are having problems with MessageBox being hidden behind other windows in certain special situations.

As @dthrasher mentions, one solution is to use a hidden dummy window. But sometimes even that is not enough. I had a situation where the solution was to not only use a hidden dummy window, but to turn on its TopMost property whenever I used it with MessageBox.

```
     _formKludge.TopMost = true;

     MessageBox.Show(_formKludge, "Nice informative message.", "Super-duper Program",
                     MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

     _formKludge.TopMost = false;
```