# Non-modal behavior of WPF MessageBox shown with SplashScreen – bug?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, splash-screen

Suppose we have the following code:

```
    void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("something");
    }
```

which is called when the App starts:

```
    <Application x:Class="AppClass.App"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 Startup="App_Startup"
                 StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
        <Application.Resources>
        </Application.Resources>
    </Application>
```

When I run it without `SplashScreen`, it runs as expected (i.e. waits for clicking `OK`), however when running together with `SplashScreen`, the message box disappears together with `SplashScreen`.

Is it a normal behavior or a bug?

Comment: *Is it a normal behavior or a bug?*... how can we answer that unless you show how you open your splash screen?

Comment: How are you showing the splash screen ? by setting image property ?

Comment: Ordinary .jpg is added via VS and set `Build Action` to `SplashScreen`. Then run the code via Ctrl+F5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will happen if you display a MessageBox and don't explicitly set the parent. The window will implicitly parent itself off whatever window is currently active (in this case, the splash screen). In the Win32 world if you close a window then all child windows will also be closed. If you explicitly set the MessageBox's parent to another window then you'll be fine.

This has been reported to microsoft [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/381980/wpf-splashscreen-closes-messagebox) and possible remedies have been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576503/how-to-set-wpf-messagebox-owner-to-desktop-window-because-splashscreen-closes-me).

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

Second parameter of SplashScreen Show(false, `false`) method is to specify whether splashscreen should be top most.

```
void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs args)
{
   SplashScreen screen = new SplashScreen("SplashImage.png");
   screen.Show(false, false);

   MessageBox.Show("something");

   splashScreen.Close(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
}
```